# PostgreSQL Logical Decoding Setup

Tags: postgresql

This may be a very basic question, but I'm struggling with it.  I'm attempting to set up logical decoding between 2 separate servers.

On the Master, I've gotten it setup so that the changes that I make to a table (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) are sent to my logical replication slot, and I can see the changes using the pg_logical_slot_get/peek_changes functions - all on my Master server.

On the Slave, I'm attempting to run the pg_revclogical command (using command prompt), however, I can't seem to get it to receive the changes made on the Master.  I've realized that no where have I told the 2 to communicate to each other.  I tried to define the host as the Master to tell the replication process that I have to pull the changes from the Master to the Slave.

I've made all of the required changes to the postgresql.conf (wal_level=logical; max_replication_slots=3; max_wal_senders=3) and pg_hba.conf (whatever it told  me to do to fix errors) files on both Master and Slave.  The pg_recvlogical command and the resulting error message are below.  Could someone please help me get my Master and Slave communicating?

```
pg_recvlogical --start --slot=wendy_test --plugin=test_decoding --dbname=testdb --file=C:\Logical_Decoding_Test.log --username=dbaadmin --host=127.##.##.### --port=5432
```

When I execute this command on the Slave, I don't receive any error messages, but it doesn't return to a command prompt either?  While it's doing its thing, I can check the database and see that the wendy_test slot is active, so it appears to be doing *something*.  However, when I INSERT a row into the table on my Master, nothing happens on my Slave (even after 5 minutes).

I can add all of the code that I have used to create the replication slots, populate the queue, etc.  I was trying to limit the amount of reading and figured those to be more basic.  Also, my end game is to transition this to have our AWS RDS system as our Slave, so any recommendations for that is appreciated as well.  THank you for your time.

Comment: Does anyone have an outline of general steps, and where the steps are to be performed (ie Master vs Slave), to get Logical Decoding to work?  I can't seem to figure out the right combination.  Could anyone tell me  what I've done incorrectly, or how I tell Logical Decoding to communicate between the 2 servers (especially this part)?  I'd appreciate ANY help.